# REST to a Javascript API, possible?

Tags: iphone, translation

So basically I have quite a dilemma and I don't have a solution.

I want to create an iPhone application that calls on the Translation and Transliteration API from Google. The translation API works in php so I can call it using a REST call from the iPhone app.

The Google transliteration API only works in JavaScript. JavaScript renders when the browser runs the JavaScript code so how would I call a JavaScript library from an iPhone app so result can return back to me?

Comment: The only thing you can try is to analyse the JavaScript Code and the Requests it sends to Google Servers e.g. using Firebug. When you know what exactly happens it shouldn't be a problem to build this request in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the javascript code from the objective c with the help of UIWebview using following

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myJSFunction(%@)", parameters]];
```

You can even get back the response [Try this trutorial](http://stevenpsmith.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/executing-javascript-from-objective-c-in-an-ios-app/)

Hope this will help you in anyways.

Comment: I will try it and get back to you.